# Error when using Symbol/Motorola Fusion dll - WinCE 6.0

Tags: c#, windows-ce

When I run any project from Visual Studio, it works excellent (on Motorola MC 3190 - WinCE 6.0)

However, when I install and run the application on the device, I get this error:

> No compatible FusionInterface dll found, Expected version is 4.1.0.1 or higher version having the format 4.x.x.x

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 2):

In my case, deploying Symbol.Fusion.dll and FusionInterface.dll files in the same directory than my executable has resolved this error.

Answer (score 1):

You must install the `symbol.all.arm.cab` file. If you are using Windows *CE* then you need the **armv4** version. If you are using Windows *Mobile*, then you need the **armv4i** version.

Also, make sure there is no local copy of the DLLs in your application's directory; this could be possibly causing a version mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a reference to `Symbol.ResourceCoordination` worked for me. Per the CS_FusionSample1 code example included with the Motorola EMDK v2.9, the relevant Symbol references are `Symbol`, `Symbol.Fusion`, and `Symbol.ResourceCoordination`.

Note, I'm building for a Motorola 9190 handheld under Windows CE 6.0.

Answer (score 0):

Fusion Interface DLL Version Compatibility

EMDK for .NET access Fusion Public API via Fusion interface DLL as mentioned in the Overview section. There can be different versions of Fusion Public API and in return many versions of Fusion Interface DLLs.

Version Incompatibility Issue

If this DLL is incompatible with EMDK, an appropriate meaningful error message will be provided in the exception when trying to access Fusion. This occurs when creating Config and WLAN objects.

Possible Messages

Older and incompatible FusionInterface dll 1.0.0.1 found. Expected version is 2.0.0.3 or higher version having the format 2.x.x.x

Newer and incompatible FusionInterface dll 3.1.0.5 found. Expected version is 2.0.0.3 or higher version having the format 2.x.x.x

Solution

The DLL version incompatibility arises because of the two files (Fusion Interface DLL and the Fusion Assembly DLL) taken from different EMDK packages. To fix the issue,

Method 1:

Remove "Symbol Managed Class Libraries" using "Remove Programs" in the control panel of the device.

Check "\Windows" folder of the device for any existence of "FusionInterface.dll" and if so, delete it.

Take the "symbol.all.arm.cab" from EMDK installed location, copy to the device and run installation.

The typical location is the appropriate sub directory (wce400\armv4 or wce500\armv4i) of "\Program Files\Enterprise Mobility Developer Kit for .NET\v2.x\SDK\Smart Devices".

Run the application.

Method2:

Copy the appropriate DLL to the \Windows directory of the device.

Run the application

Note: This DLL is not separately available in the EMDK for .NET package.